# Difference between Arrays.sort and parallelsort

Tags: java

Was going through Java 8 features, mentioned here. Couldn't understand what `parallelSort()` does exactly. Can someone explain what is the actual difference between `sort()` and `parallelSort()`?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Referring to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serial-sort-vs-parallel-sort-java/), the difference is that `sort` only make use of a single thread to sort the array. On the other hand, `parallelSort` make use of multiple thread if the array size if big enough, or use a type of quick sort (dual pivot) if it's a small array.

The main differences stated in that article are:

> 1) Arrays.sort() : is a sequential sorting.
>
> - The API uses single thread for the operation.
> - It takes bit longer time to perform the operation.
>
> 2) Arrays.ParallelSort() : is a parallel sorting.
>
> - The API uses multiple threads for the operation.
> - It’s faster when there are a lot of elements whereas slower for lesser elements.

Comment: In what scenario we can use the parallelSort? Any one please explain the scenarios in which we should use the both type of sorts